# What is the difference between V-るほうがいい and V-たほうがいい?

Tags: grammar

I would  like to know the difference in nuance between V-るほうがいい and V-たほうがいい. For example, I have heard both 休むほうがいいand 休んだほうがいい. Over the years I have heard different explanation about the difference among these two grammatical forms, but I am still not really sure about it. From what I gather, V-るほうがいい is stronger than V-たほうがいい and it can imply that it is a general advise that can be applied in different situations, and thus, it doesn not only apply to the present situation. Moreover, V-るほうがいい does not refer only to the listener, but it can also refer to the speaker him self, such in the case of 休むほうがいい that could also mean "we should take a break".  Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the simple statement 'we should rest' would be 僕たちは休んだ方がいい。

There is a good answer on Yahoo 知恵袋 [here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1314629248), which draws a comparison between 「カゼのときは、早く寝るほうがいい」and 「きょうはもう帰って寝たほうがいいよ」. Look under ベストアンサーに選ばれた回答.

Basically, the difference detailed in the explanation is between 'what you (personally) should do' and 'what one should normally do in this situation'.

Answer (score 0):

These are basically the same thing, with a slightly stronger nuance for た方がいい. But they both express "had better".