# 「言っちゃったほうが、」の意味

Tags: grammar

下の文章で「言っちゃった」は「言ってしまった」の短縮形でしょうか。

> 例）「もう正直に、みんなに**言っちゃったほう**が、いいと思うよ。」

「してしまったほうがいい」の表現を詳しく説明していただけませんか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

はい、「言っちゃった」は「言ってしまった」の口語形です。

この場合の「～てしまう」の意味は[この質問](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4781/5010)で解説されていますが、「あまり悩まずに～する」「とりあえず～する」「結果のことは心配しないで思いきって～する」のような意味です。正直に言うと、怒られたり非難されたりする悪い結果が予測できますが、それでも敢えて正直に言うべきだ、というニュアンスが含まれています。

残りの部分についてはこちらを見てください:

- [In front of "ほうがいい," is it always past tense?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24426/5010)
- [When to use　するほうがいい instead of したほうがいい in order to mean "Should do"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60907/5010)