# Differing meanings of ～しまう

Tags: grammar

I had a look before deciding to post this, but nothing really answers what I am specifically looking for.

From my understanding the following is correct (let me know if I am mistaken):

> 宿題を**してしまいました**か？ Did you finish your homework? - Bringing something to a
>   close or finish
>
> 宿題を忘**れてしまいました**。 I forgot my homework. - To accidentally do or not do
>   something.

**However I don't quite understand what it means when used with ば conditions. I think it may mean "All I have to do is ~" but I am not sure. For example:**

> 宿題を**してしまえばいい**。*(not sure if this is even grammatically correct)* All
>   I have to do is my homework.
>
> 逃げ**てしまえばいい**。 All I have to do is run away.

If someone could please explain this to me using some more example sentence that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

～てしまえばいい usually means "It's better to just do ～ (despite the risk)", "should stop worrying and do ～ ", etc. Here are related questions:

- [What are these forms: かけちゃお, つないじゃお?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4781/5010)
- [「言っちゃったほうが、」の意味](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61076/5010)

逃げてしまえばいい means something nuanced like "(Rather than confronting the difficulty) [I/you] should stop worrying and just run away".

宿題をしてしまえばいい is grammatically correct, but is semantically unlikely to happen. This may be used in a rare situation where doing homework right now might be a bad idea.